# Center text responsively horizontally and vertically over image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

This question has already been asked several times here, but I have not found my answer.

I want to position a piece of text (only few words) center, both horizontally and vertically over an image.

The image should be an img tag and not background-image.

The text should responsively adjust it self by resizing the browser window.
(I have bootstrap in my project)

[an screenshot of desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih28k.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go ^^

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>ON SALE</p>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c4/Original_Image_before_ASTC_compression.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` won't work for Safari 8 and below.

Comment: well if you want to support this you have to also include: 

-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://s3.favim.com/610/151107/art-black-and-white-geometric-minimal-Favim.com-3533393.jpg">
  <div class="text">allo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ev1cwp6q/
This solves the problem partially, the text is still not vertically centered

Comment: @Fawad Give a fixed `height` & `width` to the text as in above.

Comment: You are welcome. If it did, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

and check this link for more...  https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

```css
#container
{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    position:relative;
}

#image
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#text
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:Yellow;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:150px;   /* or in % */
    top:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg"/>
    <p id="text">
        Hello World!
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with the `<figure>` tag. I usually set it up so the `<figure>` tag contains an `<img>` and a `<div>` with the text I want at the same level.

```
  <figure>
      <img src="http://stephboreldesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/lorem-ipsum-logo.jpg">
    <div class="info">
       Content goes here
    </div> <!-- /.info -->
  </figure>
```

And the CSS so the `<figure>` tag has relative positioning and the `.info` has absolute positioning with `top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0` and a fixed `width`.

```
figure {
    margin: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

figure .info {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  background-color: rgba(233,233,233, .8);
  color: #333;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

In case you may want to add more than just 1 line of text to the `.info` container you may use an additional `<div>` with the `flexbox` positioning.

You may see the full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1fvc2whj/1/)